# Is there an API to control downloads in Firefox add-on SDK?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In Firefox, is there an API equivalent to Google Chrome's [chrome.downloads API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads)?

I need to control downloads with functions such as pause, resume, and cancel. In addition, I want to be able to remove the downloaded file.

If there is no API in Firefox add-on SDK, is it possible to do the same things in another way?

Comment: Another time, the answer to this type of question is often available with a little searching. One key in searching for such documentation is that you probably want to look for documentation on the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), or here on stackoverflow. I generally search for docs on MDN by just adding MDN to the terms I search for on Google.  For example: [MDN download API](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=MDN+download+API) would have gotten you to the right place (Downloads.jsm) by clicking on a link contained at the top of the second result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API's are (links to documentation on MDN):

- [Downloads.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm)
- [Download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm/Download)
- [DownloadTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm/DownloadTarget)
- [PlacesUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Places_utilities_for_JavaScript).There is good info at [paa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/915844/paa)'s answer to the question: [API to modify Firefox downloads list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25283194/3773011)